# Extracting data from a HTML table

Tags: curl, cut, html

**Objective:** 1) Return a *name* value from an `<a>` and 2) assess a cell value from a number of HTML table rows, conditionally returning 0 or 1

I do `curl -s http://[server-fqdn]/stats/servers?t=db | grep 'tr class="server"` which returns a varying number of rows, as illustrated in the snippet. In this case, I list db servers.

**Row snippet** (NB: full row character count is between 2,000 and 2,150 characters)

```
<tr class="server"><td class=val><a name="srv_backend_3306/server"></a></td> [cut away] <td class=val>1d3h UP</td>
```

**Challenge:** Extract the value of *name* in the first `<a>` tag and assess the content of the `<td class=val></td>` (if it contains the word UP, return 0, else return 1).

I can extend my above described curl command, adding `| cut -d\> -f3 | cut -d\" -f2` and I get the *name* - but how to get that other result? I have no unique identifier for that cell and using `cut` doesn't quite cut it due to dynamics in the table generation.

Comment: If the HTML is valid XML then you can use something like `xmlstarlet` to pick out the element value directly

Comment: There's also [`pup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) which is aimed at HTML

Comment: You can check my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little **snippet** that was inspired by [a StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7052168/931027) that you can use with native bash, you will have one function to read the content of your input and then another to parse the **dom** content :

```
#!/bin/bash
cr=1
ac=""
read_dom () {
    local IFS=\>
    read -d \< ENTITY CONTENT
    local ret=$?
    TAG_NAME=${ENTITY%% *}
    ATTRIBUTES=${ENTITY#* }
    return $ret
}

parse_dom () {
    
    if [[ $TAG_NAME == "a" ]] ; then
    eval local $ATTRIBUTES
        ac=`cut -d "=" -f2  <<< "$ATTRIBUTES" | tr -d '"'`
    fi 
    if [[ $TAG_NAME == "td" && "$(cut -d= -f1 <<< $ATTRIBUTES)" == "class" && $CONTENT == *"UP"*  ]] ; then
        cr=0 
    fi
}

while read_dom; do
    parse_dom
done  <<< "$(curl -s http://[server-fqdn]/stats/servers?t=db | grep 'tr class="server")"
echo "<a> tag content : $ac"
echo "return value for <td> check : $cr"
```

Output :

```
<a> tag content : srv_backend_3306/server
return value for <td> check : 0
```

Comment: I like this approach, but I managed to come up with a solution, that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution - it does the job, but feel free to suggest improvements ;)

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -s http://[server-fqdn]/stats/servers?t=db | grep 'tr class="server"' > hastats.html
for i in `cat hastats.html | grep 'tr class="server"' |  cut -d\> -f3 | cut -d\" -f2` ; do
grep $i hastats.html | ( ! grep -P " UP" -q)
echo $i $?
done
```

This returns e.g. `srv_backend_3306 1` for that server, which means that it was established that in this particular row, there was an occurence of the word UP with a whitespace in front. In this context, I am certain that this particular word will either be absent, or be present exactly one time for each of these particular rows.

The `! grep -P ' UP' -q` negates the returned error code, which normally would be '0' for 'occurence was found' - we want '1' returned for a particular reason.

Thanks for constructive input.

Comment: A few comments: i) avoid `for i in $(cat file)` ([see Bash pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)). You don't need it at here anyway: `grep 'tr class="server"' hastats.html | cut ...`.  ii) this will break very easily. What if you have `.foo tr { ...}` in embedded css? What if you have `<div name=footr class="server"`? iii) You only have lines matching the search pattern in `hastats.html`, why grep it again? iv) there is no need for `-P` in your `grep`. It just makes the code less portable and doesn't add anything.